# How to encode String to UTF-8 directly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encode

I must encode a String to UTF-8, in order that the German Umlaut to be correctly displayed.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
.append( "<a><div class='autocompleteName'>" + itemLabel + " (" + item.id + ")</div></a>")
```

I need to encode itemLabel variable to UTF-8.

This Java line of code I need to be able to execute in JavaScript:

```
itemLabel = new String(itemLabel.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
```

Does anyone know how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found this on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_charset.asp

set your script tag as

```
<script src="myscripts.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

maybe it works

Comment: An official reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

Answer (score -1):

How about put this meta tag to begin of your html file.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I have tried with meta tag but it does not work.

"Ä" character is still displayed as "�"